# Angular how to import a style within a component and apply it to all its children

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular material, but there is no timepicker. So as a solution I wanted to use the [ng bootstrap timepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker) within a dialog. NgBootsrap requires an import of the `bootstrap.css`, but here comes the problem. When I import it in my my `styles.scss` it overrides the Material styles. And when I import it within my component it doesn't get applied to it's children an so not to the NgBootstrap timepicker. I tried turning off the ViewEncapsulation, but this behaves like importing the styles in my `styles.scss`.

How can I import the bootstrap css within a component and apply it to all its children.

Answer (score 0):

There is a /deep/ option to force the styles into a child component. See here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deep

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to import a css file. So I can;t really change that.

Comment: The link that I provided shows the style located in the css file.

Comment: Yes, but it is not my css. It is bootstrap.